# After migrating TFS server to server projects not showing up in team explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, migration

Here is the setup:
We had a one server TFS solution previously. We split each part out so the DB, TFS and the Build Service each have their own server now.

I manually restored the TFS DBs to the new server. I installed the app tier on the app server and the Build Service on another server. As usual, everything works fine on my computer. However, about half of my team has an issue where the team explorer shows just one project. Most of the team doesn't even have permissions to view this project yet it is all they see.

I had each of them run the tf workspaces ... command to sync up their workspaces to the new server location. I verified permissions. I had one of the affected delete his workspace and create a new one. Same issue. Team explorer only shows one project... that he doesn't even have permission to view. Source control explorer seems to operate fine.

Also, this only seems to affect one project collection. I have not heard anyone on another project collection having this issue.

Suggestions?

Comment: Which version of Team Foundation Server are you using?  Did you follow this particular help article?  It is the guide for moving Team Foundation Server from one hardware configuration to another.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I'm wondering if you need to do a [ChangeServerID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee349259.aspx).